# Require HTTP (not HTTPs) in ASP.NET 5 (Core) Middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

in my old version of ASP.NET MVC 5 I have a custom filter that manage HTTPs connections. My filter forces a secured (HTTPS) request to be resent over HTTP

This is my filter:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Forces a secured (HTTPS) request to be resent over HTTP
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class RequireHttpAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"],
                "https",
                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                HandleHttpsRequest(filterContext);
            }

            return;

        }

        protected virtual void HandleHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Only redirect GET requests
                return;
            }

            string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
```

How can I do that in ASP.NET 5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the code for the built in [RequireHttpsAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/RequireHttpsAttribute.cs) and, well, make it do the opposite.

Parsing of X-Forwarded-For-* is part of another [middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides), so rather than do it yourself I'd just configure that first.

Comment: Thanks @blowdart I will do like you say ;) I don't know why people is voting down the question...